# I use float in css and I use clear: both. But divs after float's element jump on top

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have `.container-for-all-videos` with `min-height` and `height` auto. I gave `clear:both` to this container. In this container, I have few .container-for-video with float's.
After I have div with hr. This hr jumps on top. It stays on distance min-hight(container-for-all-videos), and if it is smaller than videos take - hr jumps.
I don't know how many videos will be for sure. So, I need .container-for-all-videos flexible and after it

---

. (I can't use flex, because I have to support old IE).

```css
.container-for-all-videos{    
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-height: 850px;
    height: auto;   
}
.container-for-video{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 46%;
    height: auto;  
    text-align: center;
}
.container-for-video:nth-child(odd){
    float: left;    
}
.container-for-video:nth-child(even){
    float: right;    
}
.container-for-video h4{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
hr{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;          
    border:none;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #61c2ee; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-for-all-videos">
            <div class="container-for-video">
                <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                    <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <h4>About video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-for-video">
                <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                    <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <h4>About video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-for-video">
                <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                    <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <h4>About video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-for-video">
                <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                    <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <h4>About video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-for-video">
                <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                    <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <h4>About video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-for-video">
                <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                    <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <h4>About video</h4>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give css of clear class and add `<div class="clear"></div>` after all video div.

```css
.container-for-all-videos{        
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 850px;
  height: auto;   
}
.container-for-video{
  margin: 10px;
  width: 46%;
  height: auto;  
  text-align: center;
}
.container-for-video:nth-child(odd){
  float: left;    
}
.container-for-video:nth-child(even){
  float: right;    
}
.container-for-video h4{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
hr{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;          
  border:none;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #61c2ee; 
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-for-all-videos">
  <div class="container-for-video">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
          <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <h4>About video</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="container-for-video">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
          <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <h4>About video</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="container-for-video">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
          <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <h4>About video</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="container-for-video">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
          <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <h4>About video</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="container-for-video">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
          <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <h4>About video</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="container-for-video">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
          <source src="videos/video-soccer_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <h4>About video</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps